# Kivy Place Scatter in the center of FloatLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hello I am following the Crash Course Youtube tutorials on Kivy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Gc8iYJQ_qk&t=495s

On video #8 the tutorial used the kv language to place the scatter on the center of the FloatLayout but there was an issue because every time we resize the window the scatter goes back in the center.

I want to place the scatter at the center and not move when I resize the window. The video suggested we create the property in python code so we don't have the automatic binding. Here's my code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import (Rectangle,
                           Ellipse,
                           Line,
                           Color)

import random

class ScatterTextWidget(BoxLayout):

    text_color = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
    scatter = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScatterTextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scatter.center = self.scatter.parent.center

    def change_label_color(self, *args):
        color = [random.random() for i in range(3)] + [1]
        self.text_color = color

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScatterTextWidget()
```

And this is the kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10

<ScatterTextWidget>:
    scatter: scatter_id
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: my_textinput
        font_size: 150
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 200
        text: "default"
        on_text: root.change_label_color()

    FloatLayout:
        id: float_layout
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Scatter:
            id: scatter_id
            size_hint: None, None
            size: my_label.size
            #center: self.parent.center
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.5
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Label:
                id: my_label
                text: my_textinput.text
                font_size: 150
                size: self.texture_size
                color: root.text_color
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.5
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 150
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: my_textinput.text[:3][::-1]
            font_size: 100
            color: root.text_color
        Label:
            id: label2
            text: my_textinput.text[-3:][::-1]
            font_size: 100
            color: root.text_color
```

With this code the scatter is not placed on the center of the scatter and I have no idea why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scatter` is not centered because the line:

```
self.scatter.center = self.scatter.parent.center
```

is executed too early, when the size of the `FloatLayout` is still the default of `(100,100)`, its default position is `(0,0)`, and the `center` is still the default of `(50,50)`. To get the correct centering, you must delay the execution of that line until the `size`, `pos`, and `center` are set from the `kv` file rules. To do this, you can use `Clock.schedule_once()`, like this:

```
class ScatterTextWidget(BoxLayout):

    text_color = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
    scatter = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScatterTextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.center_it)
        # self.scatter.center = self.scatter.parent.center

    def change_label_color(self, *args):
        color = [random.random() for i in range(3)] + [1]
        self.text_color = color

    def center_it(self, dt):
        self.scatter.center = self.scatter.parent.center
```

Comment: Yes that worked fine thank you very much! I had my thoughts that the problem was due to the the center line was called too early but didn't know exactly how to make it wait for everything else to load!